# How do I add text to the background?

Tags: html, css

How can you get the text in the background? I would like the title (and other additional text to be in the background) Here is the html code:

This is how it looks at the moment, screenshot of not the whole screen, photo resolution 5498x3615

[image]

```css
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Playbill;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.bg_image {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Путеводитель по городам</h1>
  <img class="bg_image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x600" alt="background for site">
</body>
```

Comment: You need to make your image a background, not an element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: By the way, your users will not be happy about loading a 20MB image. You need to reduce it to under about 200KB.

Comment: Yep, read about image formats suitable for web pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `background-image` and just put the text on top. Like this:

```css
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Playbill;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
}

body {
 background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200x600);
 background-size: cover; /* Size The Image */
 background-position: center; /* Center The Image */
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Путеводитель по городам</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this responsive solution:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Playbill;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
  }
  
.bg_image {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <h1 id="title">Путеводитель по городам</h1>
         <img class="bg_image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x600" alt="background for site">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```